# Grouping of checkbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two checkbox, I want to check one and another unchecked, and when uncheked checkbox is  checked checkbox will be unchecked.

Comment: Well, where's your code to do it then?

Comment: Note that the ASP.Net AJAX toolkit ships with a Mutually Exclusive Checkbox control; http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox.aspx

Comment: I think you want a radiobutton group? Try placing radiobuttons on a container. A `Panel` for example.

Comment: Why you want to use Checkbox instead of RadioButton. Doesn't make any sense as CheckBox are used For multiple selection while RadioButton for single selection. Use RadioButton it best fits this scenario

Comment: The answer I deleted was copied from here, if you need the information: http://forums.asp.net/p/1266989/2383885.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this..You have two checkboxes..

**Markup:**

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="CheckCheckboxes();return false"/>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" onclick="CheckCheckboxes();return false"/>
```

**Javascript:**.

```
function CheckCheckboxes() {

    if(document.getElementid('CheckBox1').checked==true)
    {
       document.getElementid('CheckBox2').checked=false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementid('CheckBox2').checked==true)
    {
       document.getElementid('CheckBox1').checked=false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why using `==` instead of `=` when assigning the `CheckBox.Checked` states?

Comment: Sorry,my mistake friend..Editted answer..

Comment: No problem, +1 for edited version.